# App not running on switching between Activities

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I have two Activities
1. List view (multiple items each with title and link)
2. Text View( when click on any item in list view, fetches the link, do xml parsing and fetch the content and displayed)

I used intent to switch from List view to text view activity. Now on first time click, it start the text view activity. On pressing devices back button, it goes again to List view. Uptil now it's all right.

The main problem is that when the second time , i click on any item in List view, Android App gives me error of "Unfortunately application has stopped" .
and On clicking "OK" , it displayed the content of second item. and when second time , i pressed back button , application got closed

Here is my Second activity

```
public class ColoumnView extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_coloumn_view);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainListActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView myColoumnView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ColoumnView);
    myColoumnView.setText(message);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // code here to show dialog
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Here is the part of my first activity where it is creating an intent

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<ContentGetter.Content> contents) {
        if (contents != null && mException == null) {
            for(int i=0; i<contents.size();i++) {
                if(contents.get(i).summary != null )
                {
                    summaryContent= contents.get(i).summary;
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainListActivity.this,ColoumnView.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, summaryContent);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d(TAG, contents.get(i).summary != null ? contents.get(0).summary : "NULL");
            }

        } else {
            if (mException instanceof IOException){
            } else if (mException instanceof XmlPullParserException) {
            }
        }


    }
```

Edit: Here is the crash Log

```
11-01 13:11:46.274    2296-2296/com.example.talha.appforblog E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.talha.appforblog, PID: 2296
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
        at com.example.talha.appforblog.MainListActivity$DownloadXmlTaskContent.onPostExecute(MainListActivity.java:241)
        at com.example.talha.appforblog.MainListActivity$DownloadXmlTaskContent.onPostExecute(MainListActivity.java:206)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log, when the null ptr exception comes

Comment: Please check, i have edited

Comment: Replace **Log.d(TAG, contents.get(i).summary != null ? contents.get(0).summary : "NULL");** with  **Log.d(TAG, contents.get(i).summary != null ? contents.get(i).summary : "NULL");**

Comment: You are right ..Thanks

Comment: One more thing. I get the content from web which is html..Now when i set my text view to that string.. It shows as it including its tags.. how could i show it as html with no tag

Comment: it shows like follows

<p> abc </p>
<a> xyz </a>

I want to show it as abc xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in line no 241 of activity MainListActivity. You are calling a print there which is not having a proper msg to print for time being comment that line. If you share the line of code in that line that would help me narrow it down

Comment: Log.d(TAG, contents.get(i).summary != null ? contents.get(0).summary : "NULL");

This is also in onPostExecute() method i pasted above. You can check the background of this line from there

Comment: since its a log statement I suppose you can do away with that. I think there is a problem with "contents.get(0).summary". Most probably its value is null

Comment: One more thing. I get the content from web which is html..Now when i set my text view to that string.. It shows as it including its tags.. how could i show it as html with no tag

Comment: it shows like follows

<p> abc </p>
<a> xyz </a>

I want to show it as abc xyz

Comment: textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlContentString));

Comment: textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p> abc </p> <a> xyz </a>"))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93901/discussion-between-pvn-and-user3585510).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is doing it...

Log.d(TAG, contents.get(i).summary != null ? contents.get(0).summary : "NULL");

Ensure that your log message is not null, in this case, contents.get(0).summary.